# IBM XPages server DNS issue

Tags: dns, xpages, lotus-notes

when using InetAddress.getByName("domain name");
using LS2J or Xpages Java I am receiving 
java.net.UnknownHostException

but if I ping from the server or I use this from lotusscript
        Set source = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        source.open "GET", sourcefile
it works fine.
If I ping from the windows server cmd it works fine.

It is almost as the JVM cannot access the DNS but everything else can.
Any ideas?

Comment: Was the host name recently changed? The JVM caches dns lookups so try a restart of http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a deeper Java issue in Java8. If your machine has an IPv6 stack enabled (or for other nefarious reasons), Java8 defaults to an IPv6 lookup, which most likely will fail. The *venerable* ActiveX object in IE is oblivious to IPv6, so the lookup works. I had this issue in other Java environments too, it isn't limited to Domino.

What you need is to add to the Java startup options the parameter

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

to ensure IPv4 is used. For setting JVM properties [see this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377792).

Hope that helps and let us know how it goes.

Comment: thanks I will check that out, pretty sure I am still on java 1.6 at the moment until I update to fp10 though

Comment: could not work this out as the JVM could never find the options file.
Where is the best place to put the file and what would the path be in Notes.ini? The article's example directory doesn't exist. Will persevere with a local server today.

Comment: In the notes program directory where the notes.ini file is

Comment: yes it was the jvm setting, i also unticked ipv6stack in the windows network adapter properties as an extra step but I am pretty sure it was the jvm setting that fixed it.